# How to bind subgrid events in expandable ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-click event for the sub grid in ui-grid(expandable ui grid) is not working. But the same ( ng-click) is working for the outer grid with ‘`grid.appScope`’ scope. But I don’t know how to bind the subgrid events in expandable grid. I have kept my code in the below plnkr. ‘Click me’ is not working in the inner grid.

There is an '`expandableScope`' property. But i am not sure how to use it. Plz see the for plnkr code [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nJLcMLBwdgPzOQUvgjQT?p=preview)

I have added below snippet in gridOptions

```
expandableRowScope: { clickMeSub: function(){alert('hi');} }
```

I tried to call clickMe method from expandableRowScope like below.

```
<button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.expandableRowScope.clickMeSub()">Click Me </button>
```

Still no luck.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nJLcMLBwdgPzOQUvgjQT?p=preview

Comment: You are calling function in "grid" object. Where is that grid object in your JS? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-click on the sub grid needs to just refer to it's own appscope, not the parent grids expandableRowScope.

```
ng-click="grid.expandableRowScope.clickMeSub()"
```

should be

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.clickMeSub()"
```

Modified Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/0o9ViW0TEuYIA4zx0kIW?p=preview